# Vectorize LDA results from Pandas column of text to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, lda

Having a large pandas column of text, I want to first train an LDA model on the whole text in that column and identify 50 topics:

```
doc_clean = df['tweet_tokenized'].tolist()
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(doc_clean)
doc_term_matrix = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc) for doc in doc_clean]
lda = LdaMulticore(doc_term_matrix, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=50)
```

Then I want to create 50 columns associated with each topic, and iterate through each row and put its probability of belonging to any of the topics to its corresponding topic(s) and put zeros for the rest of the topics.

For example, if the results of applying the trained LDA on the first row is:

```
new_doc = dictionary.doc2bow(tweet1)
results = lda(new_doc)
results:
        [(1, 0.92), (4,0.42)]
```

Meaning that tweet1 belongs to topic 1 with probability 0.92 and to topic 4 with probability 0.42, I want to have 50 new columns associated with topic 1, topic 2, ..., topic 50, and then the values for topic 1 be 0.92 and topic 4 be 0.42 and zeros for all other topics:

```
         topic1  topic2  topic3  topic4 topic5 ... topic50
tweet1   0.92    0       0       0.42   0      ... 0
```

Is there any pythonic way to do the last part (i.e. populating 50 columns) fastly?

Answer (score 0):

There is this good end-to-end tutorial covering your needs with the tools your are using, pandas and LDA: 
https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/topic-modeling-gensim-python/

The part your looking for is 18. Finding the dominant topic in each sentence, 19. Find the most representative document for each topic, and 20. Topic distribution across documents.

Comment: Thanks. But this is not what I'm looking for. I know how to parse the lda results. I'm looking for a pythonic way to vectorize the results over 50 columns.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following code and it works properly. But not sure whether it's the most efficient way:

First I create 50 columns of zeros:

```
for i in range(50):
    col_name = 'tweet_topic_'+str(i)
    df[col_name] = 0
```

Then I iterate through it using `iterrows()`:

```
for row_index, row in df.iterrows():
    row = row.copy()
    new_doc = dictionary.doc2bow(row['tweet_tokenized'])
    lda_result = lda[new_doc]
    for tpc in lda_result:
        col_name = 'tweet_topic_'+(str(tpc[0]).strip())
        print(row_index,col_name, tpc[1])
        df.loc[row_index,col_name] = tpc[1]
```